# c# Date format - UK and US

Tags: c#, datetime

I don't understand why I am finding this such a problem.

I have a simple form with a `DateTimePicker` on it (called `dtpStartDate`). I want to have **two** `DateTime` objects: one for **UK format** and one with **US format**. Something like:

```
 string str = "31/01/2018 10:00:00"; //dtpStartDate.Value.Date.ToString()

 DateTime dtUK = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
 DateTime dtUS = Convert.ToDateTime(dtUK, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

What am I doing wrong? Nothing I have tried has given me what I want, which is **two** `DateTime` objects, not a string containing the date and time.

Many thanks

Comment: `DateTime` objects are not culture specific. But it can display the date and time in different formats in a string representation.

Comment: `DateTime` is not culture specific. When you convert that to a string you can pass the culture you want

Comment: maybe you can get 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Unless of course, you are asking how to convert a DateTime to a given time zone, such as converting a UK GMT DateTime to a US EST DateTime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of a DateTime object as:

```
public class DateTime
{
    public int Year;
    public int Month;
    public int Day;
    public int Hours;
    public int Minutes;
    public int Seconds;
    public int Milliseconds;
}
```

That's all it stores, it doesn't contain any Culture-related information.  If you were to create two DateTime objects "for UK Format and US Format", they would be identical and contain the same data.

However, when you call the `ToString()` method on a DateTime object, you can pass it a CultureInfo parameter.  That parameter tells the DateTime object how to output those values into the resultant string.

So for a UK CultureInfo with `ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB")`, it outputs a string containing `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.
And for a US CultureInfo with `ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")`, it outputs a string containing `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

DateTime contains general datetime information. You can make a culture specific string representation. Try this:

```
string str = "31/01/2018 10:00:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
var uk = dt.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB")); //31/01/2018 10:00:00
var us = dt.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")); //1/31/2018 10:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string str = "31/01/2018 10:00:00"; //dtpStartDate.Value.Date.ToString()

DateTime dateTimeUK = DateTime.Parse(str, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
DateTime dateTimeUS = DateTime.Parse(str, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```